# How to make method private and inherit it in Coffeescript?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, private-members

How to make method "btnClick" private?

```
class FirstClass
  constructor: ->
    $('.btn').click @btnClick

  btnClick: =>
    alert('Hi from the first class!')

class SecondClass extends FirstClass
  btnClick: =>
    super()
    alert('Hi from the second class!')

@obj = new SecondClass
```

http://jsfiddle.net/R646x/17/

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There's no private in JavaScript so there's no private in CoffeeScript, sort of. You can make things private at the class level like this:

```
class C
    private_function = -> console.log('pancakes')
```

That `private_function` will only be visible within `C`. The problem is that `private_function` is just a function, it isn't a method on instances of `C`. You can work around that by using [`Function.apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) or [`Function.call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call):

```
class C
    private_function = -> console.log('pancakes')
    m: ->
        private_function.call(@)
```

So in your case, you could do something like this:

```
class FirstClass
    btnClick = -> console.log('FirstClass: ', @)
    constructor: ->
        $('.btn').click => btnClick.call(@)

class SecondClass extends FirstClass
    btnClick = -> console.log('SecondClass: ', @)
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/5v3sH/

Or, if you don't need `@` in `btnClick` to be anything in particular, you can just use the function as-is:

```
class FirstClass
    btnClick = -> console.log('FirstClass')
    constructor: ->
        $('.btn').click btnClick
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/zGU7H/

Comment: btnClick = -> console.log('SecondClass: ', @) never executes

Comment: @Jonas: No it doesn't, you said you wanted something "private" and to me that means "only visible in FirstClass". There is no public/private/protected in JavaScript so it isn't in CoffeeScript either, at best you can sort of simulate it in some cases.

Comment: Should I bother hiding methods at all? What is general practice? Maybe  there is js naming convention for "private" methods?

Comment: I don't bother with visibility that much in (Coffee|Java)Script, the languages don't support it so any attempt at controlling visibility is a kludge at best. The closest thing to a convention I've seen is a leading underscore (`_some_private_method: -> ...`) but you still have to be fully aware of the structure of all your ancestor classes.

Comment: I think the best reason to use the leading underscore is so that THE AUTHOR remembers that the method isn't intended to be used outside the class when she comes back 2 months later to enhance the code. It is short, generally accepted, and easy to remember its purpose.

Comment: @randomfactor: Oh come on, no ever has to read their own code two months later :) I quite often use plain functions ("class" scope or file scope) for that sort of thing; but if I need a method then a leading underscore in the name is my preferred signal that it is for internal use only.