# CoffeeScript - understanding "@"

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I have read several papers on CoffeeScript OOP. From them, do I understand correctly that using the `@` sign in CoffeeScript (and `this` prefix in JavaScript):

- for variables: makes variables members of a class instance. Each instance has it's own such variable (non-static variable)
- for "methods": makes methods static, which is contrary to what it does with variables

I am a noob in JS and CS, sorry. Their philosophy is quite different from what I am used to.

**UPDATE**

Here are references on the info that I have read:

- [reference-1](http://elegantcode.com/2011/07/26/exploring-coffeescript-part-4-objects-and-classes/)
- [reference-2](http://www.gridlinked.info/oop-with-coffeescript-javascript/#statics)

just search for `static`.

Comment: "for "methods": makes methods static" -  I don't see anything that suggests this anywhere.

Comment: Are you asking anything?

Comment: @lanzz: yes, sorry if the question is a bit unclear, but it as it says in the original post: "do I understand correctly that..." so you could say just "yes", "no" or something else regarding the issue, for example, something like that I misunderstand the word `static` there, which is possible...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Inside a method, `@` is JavaScript's `this` and refers to the current object; the current object depends on how the method is called, see [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) and [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) for ways to mess around with a method's `@` (AKA `this`); you can also [use `=>` to bind a method](http://coffeescript.org/#fat_arrow) to an object in CoffeeScript.

If you say `@p = 11`, that's the same as `this.p = 11` and makes `p` available in that object.

Inside a class definition, `@` refers to the class itself. So this:

```
class C
    @m: -> ...
```

defines a class method and you can say `C.m()` to execute it.

Consider this example:

```
class C
    a: -> @p = 11
    b: -> console.log(@p)
    @c: -> console.log('Class method')

C.c()            // This calls the class method.
o = new C
o.b()            // There is no 'o.p' yet.
o.a()            // This sets 'o.p'.
o.b()            // And now we see an 'o.p'.
console.log(o.p) // And we see o.p here as well.
```

That will give you this output in the console:

```
Class method
undefined
11
11
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/DFcRt/

These might also be of interest:

- [Variable types in CoffeeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9347782/479863)
- [How to make method private and inherit it in Coffeescript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10612293/479863)
  ​

Comment: perfect answer! that's what all the papers I've read had missing.