# Coffeescript, classes and functions

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

In JavaScript I'd set up a class like:

```
var SomeClass = (function()
{
    var _this   = { };
    var privateVar = 'foo'

    _this.publicVar = 'bar'

    function privateFunction()
    {
        return privateVar;
    }

    _this.publicFunction = function()
    {
        return _this.publicVar;
    }

    return _this;
})();
```

This is fine as in `privateFunction` I can reference `publicFunction` by either calling `SomeClass.publicFunction()` or `_this.publicFunction()`

Now in Coffeescript I'm trying to set up my class so that I can call class functions, how do I go about this? How can I create a class in coffeescript called `Foo` and get a function in the class to reference another function in that class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is confusing.

If you want to create a **class method**, you could do it like

```
class Foo
  constructor: ->        

  m1: ->
    Foo.classMethod()

  m2: ->
    @privateMethod()
    @m1()

Foo.classMethod = ->
```

note the last line.  A class method is one that lives on the function that defines the class.

If you want to call a method from another method, its no big deal.  `m1` and `m2` in this example demonstrate this.  Note that each invocation is scoped to `this`, which is the current **instance** of your class Foo.  So you could do

```
f = new Foo()
f.m2()
```

which would create a new **instance** of Foo, and then invoke `m2` on that instance.  `m2` in turn invokes the **class method** `classMethod`.

[Check this out](http://coffeescript.org/#try%3a%0Aclass%20Foo%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20constructor%3A%20-%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20m1%3A%20-%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Foo.classMethod%28%29%0A%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20m2%3A%20-%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%40privateMethod%28%29%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%40m1%28%29%0A%0A%20%20%20%20Foo.classMethod%20%3D%20-%3E) to see the javascript to which the above coffeescript compiles.

Comment: So how about 'private' functions?

Comment: updated -- you do it in your constructor.  Check out the link at the bottom so you can see the js

Comment: @AhmedNuaman, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10612293/how-to-make-method-private-and-inherit-it-in-coffeescript re private

Comment: @AhmedNuaman: This one might also be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9347782/479863

Answer (score 2):

I think this would help :

```
class Foo
  a: ->
    alert 'a invoked'
  b: ->
    @a()
    alert 'b invoked'
new Foo().b()
```

Comment: So how about 'private' functions?

Answer (score 0):

Invoking public method inside a private method

method a is private and method b is public

```js
class Foo
  call_a: ->
    a.call(this)
  b: ->
    alert 'b invoked'
  a = ->
    alert 'a invoked'
    @b()

obj = new Foo
obj.call_a()
```