# Closured constructor locals in CoffeeScript

Tags: constructor, coffeescript, closures

Sometimes I write my JS classes like this:

```
mylib.Container = function() {
  var things = [];

  // Returns the index of the image added
  this.addItem = function(item)
  {
    things.push(item)
  }
}
...
var c = new mylib.Container();
c.addItem(whatever);
```

I use "constructor-scoped" closured variables (like `things`) to avoid `this` scoping issues, and I am also using them in tight loops (like the ones used in `requestAnimationFrame`). These variables never bleed to the outside of the created fubject.

Is there a way to create and use such variables in CoffeeScript? I know that I have the `@ivar` notation which is shorter than `this` but something is telling me acessing a closured `var`might still be faster...

Comment: See highest voted answer, not the accepted one.

Comment: Thanks! will read into it

Comment: Also similar to [How to make method private and inherit it in Coffeescript?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10612293/479863) or at least the answer might be useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, you're assigning function in the constructor. You can do that in coffee as well

```
myLib.container = ->
  things = []

  @addItem = (item) -> things.push item

  this
```

or if you *really* want to use the class syntax

```
class myLib.container
  constructor: ->
    things = []
    @addItem = (item) -> things.push item
```

Comment: If I do this using the class syntax, `things` will not be available outside of the constructor scope. Or is constructor scope the same as the function scope in my example?

Comment: That's why I added `@addItem` in the constructor